Are second-order conditions in optimization really needed?
I’m participating in optimization course and a lot of time is spent proving second-order conditions for unconstrained and constrained problems. To me these conditions feel rather unnecessary since I could just solve the first-order conditions to get the candidate points and them plug them into the objective function to see which is the minimum and which is the maximum.
Doesn’t my way always work or am I missing something?
More precisely, I just usually find the zeroes of the gradient of the Lagrangian and then one by one plug them into the objective function. Then I pick the point that gives the minimum/maximul value. So why bother checking for definitiness of Hessian?

Maximize $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ subject to $xy=1$

Also, finding a saddle point is a waste of effort. In high dimensions (think hundreds to billions), saddle points are far more likely to occur than extrema. It is just more efficient to only look for stationary points with definite Hessians

Okey so this is likely just a thing for the too well behaving examples in the textbooks.

@whpowell96 But in the case of billions of saddle points. How is it faster or more efficient to check Hessian for all points than just to plug them into the objective function? I think this is half of my confusion.

When you get problems that big, even finding a single point is hard. For that reason, you use search techniques that steer you towards places with definite Hessians. You essentially create an algorithm such that when it terminates, you get a point satisfying the second order conditions. Quasinewton methods are one such class of algorithms. Also, the extrema is only guaranteed to be one of that stationary points if the constraint set is compact, which is not always the case. See my first problem as an example
